# Solr query data which matches 2 or more keywords

Tags: solr, lucene, solr5

I am using `Solr version 5` for searching data. I am using below query to which returns results even `single keyword` is matched.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/document/select?q=keyword1+keyword2&wt=json
```

Can anyone suggest me query to fetch results only if `2 or more` keywords matched.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [dismax `mm` (minimum should match) parameter](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#mm_.28Minimum_.27Should.27_Match.29)

```
q=keyword1+keyword2&defType=dismax&mm=2&wt=json
```

Answer (score 0):

In your solrconfig.xml, change the default value of q.op to AND.

```
<str name="q.op">AND</str>
```